# After migration of website, it will not work anymore. Blank php page. Any Ideas?

Tags: php, ubuntu, web, migration

I switched on the error screens, but the errors are just warnings, so nothing critical.

I added an .html file in the websites folder with some text like "yes it works" 
and this is displayed. So it should word.... I don't have any ideas left.

---

The migration was from ubuntu server 10.10 to ubuntu 12.04 server, fresh installed.
I installed everything (LAMPP ofc)... PHP Myadmin for example is working and my MYSQL databases are working as well. I can also display the info.php page in every webpage folder.

I have another website running on the apache2 server, which is working fine.

I am out of ideas. any help will be upvoted fastly.

Thanks in advance

```
Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/index.php on line 11
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/DB.php on line 311 
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/DB.php on line 385 
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/DB.php on line 923 
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/HTML/AJAX/Server.php on line 161 
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/HTML/AJAX.php on line 612 
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/HTML/AJAX/Serializer/JSON.php on line 46 
Warning: include_once(../pear/Net/Socket.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 25 
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../pear/Net/Socket.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Net/SMTP.php on line 25 
Warning: include_once(PEAR.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Mail/mime.php on line 65 
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'PEAR.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Mail/mime.php on line 65
Warning: include_once(../pear/Mail/mimePart.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Mail/mime.php on line 75
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../pear/Mail/mimePart.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Mail/mime.php on line 75
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/Workbook.php on line 180
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/Workbook.php on line 189
Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/modules/statistics/frontend.class.php on line 16
Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/modules/users/frontend.class.php on line 19
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/DB/common.php on line 958
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/pear/DB/common.php on line 1150
Notice: DB Error: connect failed in /data/xxxx/www/classes/registry.class.php on line 70

That'y my Error log.
```

So here is the Code from the DB ERROR :

```
function GetDbEngineService()
    {
            $conf = $this->conf;
            $type = $this->config['system']['db']['type'];
            $host = $this->config['system']['db']['host'];
            $user = $this->config['system']['db']['user'];
            $pass = $this->config['system']['db']['pass'];
            $db_name = $this->config['system']['db']['db_name'];

            $dsn = "$type://$user:$pass@$host/$db_name";
            $engine = DB::connect($dsn);
            $this->db_engine = $engine;

            if (DB::isError($engine)) {
                    user_error  ( $engine->getMessage());
                    exit();
            }

            $engine->query("set names utf8");
            return $engine;
    }

    function GetSettings()
```

Does this help ? Since I am not a prof. coder in php ...

EDIT : Now i fixed the DB Problem , and have this error ( i deeted the warnings and deprecated)

```
Notice: Undefined variable: row in /data/xxxx/www/classes/web_logic.class.php on line 238 Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/classes/web_interface.class.php on line 159 
Notice: Undefined index: special in /data/xxxx/www/classes/web_interface.class.php on line 162 Notice: Undefined variable: row in /data/xxxx/www/classes/web_logic.class.php on line 34 
Notice: Undefined variable: header in /data/xxxx/www/classes/web_logic.class.php on line 42 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /data/xxxx/www/classes/web_interface.class.php on line 56 
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /data/xxxx/www/classes/web_interface.class.php on line 60 Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /data/xxxx/www/classes/web_view.class.php on line 320 
Notice: Undefined index: ajax_action in /data/xxxx/www/classes/web_interface.class.php on line 132
```

0

Comment: This is impossible to answer, we can't see what's going on on your web site.

Comment: do you have error log? if you have see it.

Comment: Set maximum level of error logging. Check your error logs. We also can not guess that for you.

Comment: atleast post the warnings

Comment: Turn on error logging and check teh server error logs

Comment: As is already said, just warning from Deprecated functions.  That should display something else than a blank screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Notice: DB Error: connect failed in /data/xxxx/www/classes/registry.class.php on line 70
```

Is probably the root of your problem.

You are unable to connect to your database for some reason.

Make sure your database server is running and that you have permissions to connect from your new server

Comment: added that part from registry.class.php about the DB.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, Have you checked if your database server is running and that you have permissions to connect from your new server

Comment: the database is on the same machine, and it is working. at least i can access from phpmyadmin and see all entries.

Comment: Can you access it using the same settings you have configured in your php files?

Comment: I dumped the mysql files from the old server. and restored it here. So everything should be the same. Btw. it's not my page and I am new to this topic. So how to check it? thanks

Comment: Find your applications config files and try using the same username and password in phpmyadmin.

Comment: thanks, that helped for the db error. now i found the username and password and gave him some user rights :). i also added my "new" error log without warnings